# How do I groupby and concat a list in a Dataframe Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns with data as below

```
+----+-----------------+
|acct|           device|
+----+-----------------+
|   B|       List(3, 4)|
|   C|       List(3, 5)|
|   A|       List(2, 6)|
|   B|List(3, 11, 4, 9)|
|   C|       List(5, 6)|
|   A|List(2, 10, 7, 6)|
+----+-----------------+
```

And I need the result as below

```
+----+-----------------+
|acct|           device|
+----+-----------------+
|   B|List(3, 4, 11, 9)|
|   C|    List(3, 5, 6)|
|   A|List(2, 6, 7, 10)|
+----+-----------------+
```

I tried as below but ,it seems to be not working

`df.groupBy("acct").agg(concat("device"))`

`df.groupBy("acct").agg(collect_set("device"))`

Please let me know how can I achieve this using Scala?

Comment: @sb0709 There is no such function as `GroupConcat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option that *might* perform better than the `explode` option: creating your own **UserDefinedAggregationFunction** that merges lists into distinct sets.

You'll have to extend `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` as follows:

```
class MergeListsUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Seq(StructField("a", ArrayType(IntegerType))))

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = inputSchema

  override def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(IntegerType)

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = buffer.update(0, mutable.Seq[Int]())

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val existing = buffer.getAs[mutable.Seq[Int]](0)
    val newList = input.getAs[mutable.Seq[Int]](0)
    val result = (existing ++ newList).distinct
    buffer.update(0, result)
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = update(buffer1, buffer2)

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = buffer.getAs[mutable.Seq[Int]](0)
}
```

And use it like so:

```
val mergeUDAF = new MergeListsUDAF()

df.groupBy("acct").agg(mergeUDAF($"device"))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can start by exploding the `device` column and continue as you did - but note that it might not preserve the order of the lists (which anyway isn't guaranteed in any group by):

```
val result = df.withColumn("device", explode($"device"))
  .groupBy("acct")
  .agg(collect_set("device"))

result.show(truncate = false)
// +----+-------------------+
// |acct|collect_set(device)|
// +----+-------------------+
// |B   |[9, 3, 4, 11]      |
// |C   |[5, 6, 3]          |
// |A   |[2, 6, 10, 7]      |
// +----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `collect_set` and `Window`. In your case:

```
df.withColumn("device", collect_set("device").over(Window.partitionBy("acct")))
```

Comment: I guess this will result in nested arrays